# Is it possible to still see old windows 7 documents?

Tags: partitioning

I have recently installed Ubuntu and it is working great. The Question I have is when Ubuntu was installed did it use a separate partion on the hard drive? the reason I ask is because There are a number of documents that I had created in windows 7 that I would like to use if possible,But I am unsure as to get at them.

Comment: Check the output from: **`sudo update-grub`**. *Does this show a Windows-7 partition?*

Comment: post the o/p of `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: I have just tried sudo update-grub but it showed only linux. so I guesse I have not got the windows files anymore.The result of sudo fdisk -l is    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   625141759   312320001    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   625141759   312320000   8e  Linux LVM
 so i guesse that confirms it, So thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you selected during Ubuntu installation. At some point a dialogue similar to this one should have been shown:

[image: Guided Partitioning Dialogue]

If you selected the first option, then your documents are still there. As Luis posted, in that case you should simply be able to access the Windows partition in Nautilus.

If however you selected the second option, that deletes "all of your Windows programs, documents, photos, music, and all other files", then your old documents are no longer accessible, and were possibly already overwritten, so that even professional data recovery companies will no longer be able to restore them.

If you chose the third option, you partitioned manually and you should remember what you did with the Windows partition...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I cannot remember which option I chose when I installed but I think I chose option one. However, if I did not then How do I open Nautilis in order to see?

Comment: Read this documentation -- [MountingWindowsPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions) when you're sure you opted for `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7` or installed through `Something else` perfectly

Comment: If you run Nautilus (the default filemanager on Ubuntu), you should have all connected devices and all (detected) partitions listed in the bar on the left. I'm afraid I don't have a Ubuntu PC handy, so I can only link to a screenshot on the web: http://www.securitronlinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/nautilus.png There's also a program called disk-utility (I think) that displays all partitions on your HDDs. You can use that to see if there are any Windows partitions left (they have NTFS or FAT file systems)

Answer (score 0):

Are you dual booting? When you were installing Ubuntu, did you erase entire disk or install side by side as the installer prompt you to do so? When you open Nautilis are you able to see various file systems under devices? If so look for your Windows file system to access your documents.

Luis

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I cannot remember which option I chose when I installed but I think I chose option one. However, if I did not then How do I open Nautilis in order to see?

Answer (score 0):

If you dual booted, and an easy way to see if you did and to grab those files, head to File system from nautilus and see if there is a folder called "host" if there is, then you are able to get your documents, if not, you can't, to get them if you have that folder, you simply open it, and it shows the content of your windows 7 stuff, you should see a folder called "users", "windows", and "program files" just head into users select your main folder an viola, your windows seven stuff.